# Centos Crontab Bad Command

Tags: linux, cron, centos6.5

I have a pretty simple db back-up script that runs perfectly from shell.

```
php /home/db_backup/db_backup.php
```

When I attempt to add a Crontab, I get the vague 'Bad Command errors in crontab, can't install."

I've tried w/ php and full path to php.

```
which php
```

returns /usr/bin/php

```
* 1 * * * php /home/db_backup/db_backup.php

* 1 * * * /usr/bin/php /home/db_backup/db_backup.php
```

Both return the same error.

Centos 6.6. logged in as root. Editing crontab thusly

```
crontab -e
```

Spent too many hours trying to get this working. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I bet your problem is when editing the crontab file not with the commands itself.

Be sure to let a blank line at the end of file.

I mean the cursor must be in an empty line after the last entry.

Comment: Well fersnizzle! I've edited that crontab multiple times before and never had that problem. But it works now. Thanks loads.

Comment: Just did a full test and works perfectly. Thanks again. 

Was wondering if it's normal that the only way to exit insert mode and get back to command mode in the crontab editor is with <ctrl> c? 
Esc doesn't do anything.

Comment: Actually it depends in the text editor, you can always run the command like this: **EDITOR=vim crontab -e**. Just replace **vim** with your prefered text editor. And of course, you can set the variable permanently in your shell load script (like .bashrc for Bash shell).